# How to know how much overshoot/undershoot the compass if you're flying close to one of the poles; is it even needed?

Tags: magnetic-compass

As far as I understand, the formula (1/2LAT + 15°) is not applicable when flying close to one of the poles or the equator.Therefore, when flying close to the poles, what happens? Does it have the same effect as when you're at the equator? Does the magnetic dip become insignificant enough so that the compass lag/leading may be neglected?

Comment: Are you talking about VFR or IFR?  If IFR with no directional gyro, you normally do timed turns.

Comment: If you’re flying between the North Pole and magnetic north, the two will differ by 180 degrees.  Also, the magnetic South Pole isn’t diametrically opposed to magnetic north; there’s no simple formula

Comment: If you're flying really close to the magnetic poles, the compass becomes fairly useless anyway.  In the far north you fly by true headings and tracks.

Answer (score 2):

> As far as I understand, the formula (1/2LAT + 15°) is not applicable
> when flying close to one of the poles or the equator.Therefore, when
> flying close to the poles, what happens? Does it have the same effect
> as when you're at the equator? Does the magnetic dip become
> insignificant enough so that the compass lag/leading may be neglected?

Re the question in the last sentence quoted above: *definitely not*.  Magnetic dip is actually *more pronounced near the magnetic poles* than anywhere else on earth.

See for example http://geokov.com/education/magnetic-declination-inclination.aspx -- the second of the two charts shows magnetic "inclination", or "dip".

A good visualization of the strong "dip" in the earth's magnetic field lines near the magnetic poles is provided on [this web page](https://www.bradford.ac.uk/archaeomagnetism/archaeomagnetic-dating/magnetic-field/).

The strong "dip" in the earth's magnetic field lines near the magnetic poles is one of the main reasons why it is so difficult to use a magnetic compass near the magnetic poles.